Is there a clean way to call stepfun many times to generate a matrix?
MWE:
library(stats)

months <- 1:12
months_plus_one <- months |> append(months[length(months)] + 1)

hours_list <- lapply(months_plus_one, \(m)(stepfun(c(m), c(0, 50))(months)))
hours <- do.call(rbind, hours_list)

This generates a matrix, where each row comes from a call to stepfun.
This feels like a messy way of turning a vector (months) into a matrix (hours).

Is there a cleaner way of doing this, which exploits the fact that R is designed to work with vectorised functions?
If months were a column of a dataframe, would tidyverse provide a nicer syntax?


t(sapply(months_plus_one, \(m)(stepfun(c(m), c(0, 50))(months))))?

t(sapply(c(months, months[length(months)] + 1L), \(m) stepfun(m, c(0, 50))(months)))

Is stepfun() needed? Haven't checked the source code yet, perhaps: stringi::stri_list2matrix(Vectorize(\(x) rep(50, x))(12:0), byrow = TRUE, fill = 0L) |> type.convert(as.is = TRUE). Pretty sure we can get rid of Vectorise(). I will come back later.

If stepfun() is no requirement. Avoiding stri_list2matrix would be straightforward, but requires loops to append zeros.
